# using html/css technique to change colors, but its getting them wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to set up a table where the numbers for yesterday are compared to the target, if yesterday is higher then target its green (as a css class text-success) and otherwise orange if lower. This is the code. The part in brackets is where my question is, as I don't know what its called.

For some reason, even when target is 100 and yesterday was 45, it'll show green?

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data.rows">

    <td><span class="h1 text-white">{{ row.target | number}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="text-{{ row.yesterday > row.target ? 'success' : 'warning' }}" style="font-size: 2.6em">{{ row.yesterday | number}}</span></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a jfiddle/plunker?

Comment: Look in your developer tools; does the class always get set to `"text-success"` or does it get set to something like `"text-"`?  If you could toss this into a fiddle that would be helpful.

Comment: I don't entirely understand it, but the way it seems to work(this is a piece of html that was already here) if row.yesterday > row.target it inserts 'success' and otherwise 'warning' so the html product becomes "text-success" or "text-warning"

Comment: So the correct class name is getting inserted? Just the color is off? I'm having a hard time picturing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code should be working.

Here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5942zs8o/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data.rows">
      <td><span class="h1 text-white">{{ row.target | number}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="text-{{ row.yesterday > row.target ? 'success' : 'warning' }}" style="font-size: 2.6em">{{ row.yesterday | number}}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.rows = [ 
                {
                    "yesterday" : 50,
                    "target": 100
                },
                {
                    "yesterday" : 100,
                    "target": 100

                },
                {
                    "yesterday" : 150,
                    "target": 100
                }
            ];
});
```

CSS:

```
.text-warning {
    color: #FFA500;
}

.text-success {
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ng-class:

```
ng-class="row.yesterday > row.target ? 'text-success' : 'text-warning'"
```